# page number inside section

Tags: ms-word, bi-publisher

I have a section and I am trying to use the page number from word and I am getting page 1 in all pages.

I try link headers but I don't want the same header n my last page

```
header 
<?for-each@section:G_1?>
                               page1/2 

here is table i want to show up in every page 

<?end for-each?> 
-------------------------------------------
main body i have some groub by in tables 
----------------------------------
i have different  last page that calculate all my resuts and with no header 

page1/2 <here is the error i want 1,2,3,4/120>   and iam getting 1,1,1,1,1,1,1/2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sections will reset page numbers.

You can bypass this by putting the following code anywhere in your template:

```
<?initial-page-number:'AUTO'?>
```